# CakePHP CSS difficulty

Tags: php, mysql, css, cakephp-2.0

Im using CakePHP 2.0 as a framework for my website, I'm having some difficulty with the CSS.
Basically what is going wrong is that I have my CSS file being defined on the default.ctp page. It works on this page, however if I navigate to localhost/evolvidsnew/users/login the css is not being used so theres no background colours or position changes etc
on the default.ctp I have used the following line,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="App/webroot/css/style.css"/>
```

am I doing something wrong here?
Would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a path issue. Try an absolute path to your CSS file.

Comment: try using just `/css/style.css` cake uses App/webroot as the main directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work properly you should use the Html helper from CakePHP core library:

> <?php echo $this->Html->css('style'); ?>

This should make the style work on every page.

Oh, and the HtmlHelper should be loaded automatically, if it isn't, add this to your controller class:

> public $helpers = array('Html');

For more information about HtmlHelper and other core libraries, visit http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries.html#helpers

Comment: how would this apply if I wanted to load up a jquery file for actions etc?

Comment: It is explained in the link I posted. Can be done through echo $this->Html->script('nameofyourfile.js');

Comment: yeah i checked out that link and got it sorted many thanks again

Answer (score 2):

With default configuration CakePHP redirects all requests to the root of the site to app/webroot.

So for your case you should use `/css/style.css`